# Assigning R variable to bash

Tags: r, bash

I want to assign the output of an R operation to a bash script as `CALC` for further processing in bash. I would run R within the bash script using the following.

```
CALC=($(Rscript calc.R "arg.$j"))
echo $CALC
```

On testing `echo $CALC` prints `"Microsoft"` which is the first word of the R invoke message. An example Rscript is as follows.

```
targetFile <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
gg <- data.table::fread(file = targetFile, data.table=F)
sum(gg$V1, gg$V2)
```

I expect `echo $CALC` would print the sum of the two columns of file `gg` which is a numeric value. How to stop printing R invoke message but the result of the last command? Thanks

Comment: If `r` is so surprisingly unfriendly to print some license information to **stdout**, and you don't find an option to suppress this unfriendly behaviour, you will have to bite the bullet and filter out the initial lines, for instance using `tail`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post here the complete text your calc.R is producing.

Comment: Just an idea: Could it be that this information does not come directly from R, but from a profile file it processes? What happens if you use the `--vanilla` option?

Comment: @user1934428 I wrote a file including the output of R and read the file back in bash.  --vanilla also printed out the R invoke message.

Comment: Maybe it would then be a good idea to file a change request for R, that that information is printed to stderr instead of stdout?

Answer (score 2):

the `cat()` function is used to print the result without any additional text or messages and by using `cat(result)`, only the numeric value of the sum will be printed!

```
targetFile <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
gg <- data.table::fread(file = targetFile, data.table = FALSE)
result <- sum(gg$V1, gg$V2)
cat(result)
```

now you are able to capture the output of the R script using command substitution `$()` and assign it to the `CALC` variable like this:

```
CALC=$(Rscript calc.R "arg.$j")
echo $CALC
```

Comment: Adding ```cat``` did not resolve. Still, I get the R intro message as output.